# Multiple Symfony forms on one page

Tags: symfony, ezpublish

is it possible have 3 or more forms on the same page  with same class in ez publish 5 ?

when i  put  3 form like this

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form_widget(form) }}
 {{ form_end(form) }}

 {{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form_widget(form) }}
 {{ form_end(form) }}


 {{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form_widget(form) }}
 {{ form_end(form) }}
```

render only first  form  not others.

and the second question , i want  use one class for multiple forms in ez publish, is it possible ?

any link or suggest would be helpful for me

Comment: is it the same form?

Comment: your question was not quite clear. you want to create forms from ez Classes and create objects in frontend instead of /ez Backoffice ? how does your controller look like ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use form in form.

Example Form 1:

```
class MyRegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstname', TextType::class, array(
                'label_attr' => ['style' => 'display:none'],
                'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'form.profile.firstname']
            ));
    }
}
```

Example Form 2:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // Add Self Form
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array(
                'attr' => ['placeholder' => 'form.email'],
                'label_attr' => ['style' => 'display:none'],
                'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle',
            ));

        // Include First Form
        $builder->add('Profile', MyRegistrationType::class, array(
            'mapped' => true,
            'label' => false,
            'required' => true
        ));
    }
}
```

Using Form in Controller:

```
// Create Form
$form = $this->createForm(RegistrationType::class);
```

Render Twig:

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}
 {{ form_widget(form) }}
 {{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: more than symfony this question is about ezpublish Class and you have not addressed it at all!